# lighttpd: access POST data in C

Tags: lighttpd, httpserver

I have the following C code flow:

```
httpd *server;
...
httpdReadRequest(server, timeout);
...
```

Now I want to access data from a post request as this one:

```
wget --post-data="dumyData" http://192.168.59.254/path
```

The call `httpdRequestContentLength(server)` returns 8, which is the length of post data.

How can I access the post data?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified what library you are using which provides httpdReadRequest() and httpdRequestContentLength().  If you're using the ancient libhttpd, then check the httpd.h header file for httpdGet*() interfaces, as the POST data is read and decoded, and accessible via httpdGetVariableBy*() and httpdGetNextVariableByPrefix() interfaces.